# Different value returned from Cron than interactively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

The below checks to ensure that three particular services are running within a vendor application, and sends a warning e-mail if not.  When the services are all running I receive a value of 3 when the command is run interactively in bash (default) and therefore the nice message prints.  When done via Cron, however, the value returned is zero, which is not correct.  $? outputs 0, and so I don't suspect that any error necessarily occurs when executed in Cron.  The crontab job is under root, which is the user I am using to execute the command interactively.

Thoughts?

---

````
epVar=$(/opt/ais/bin/ais_status -l --instance Act_WLF -u admin -p password | egrep 'AML_EWLF_loadSearchConfigurationSublists|INFRA_DBQ_startQueueListener|AML_EWLF_startOnDemandRealtimeProcess' | /usr/bin/wc -l)
if [ $epVar -ne 3 ]; then
        echo $epVar > epVar.txt
        echo $? >> epVar.txt
        #/usr/sbin/sendmail -vt < RTEPMail.txt
else
        echo "All 3 RT services running :>)"
fi```
````

Comment: `echo $? >> epVar.txt` will output the status of the preceding `echo $epVar > epVar.txt` command, not the status of the `/opt/ais/bin/ais_status` or `wc` command. Try dumping the output of `/opt/ais/bin/ais_status -l --instance Act_WLF -u admin -p password ` to a file and see if it looks right. Maybe it uses environment variables that cron doesn't provide.

Comment: Well, that outputs nothing but I do see, outside of the script in interactive mode:

[root@puflopactmzaa02 ~]# echo $?
127

, so this definitely seems to be the case.  I'll dig further.

Comment: Indeed, after exporting PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH this seems to work.  I don't know why yet, as PATH only contained very basic directories (/usr/bin, /usr/sbin), and so I suspect that it was LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I'll found out for sure to satisfy my own curiosity.  If you post your comment as an answer then I'll accept it, since it helped to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, was LD_LIBRARY_PATH set earlier in the script?

Comment: It was not, no.  I set it after your comment.